# Ownership of a house if no owner can be found

Tags: internal-consistency, law, history

Background:

Currently I am working on a haunted-house story. The house in this story, has existed for an undetermined amount of time (how and when it was build is not really important for the story).
But the characters in the story will investigate the houses history.

My current plan is that after World War 2 the house was "discovered". It was noticed that the cadastral office had no
information about the houses existence or the owner of the land the house stands on. Furthermore no one could be found who knew anything about it. The official reason given for this lack
of information will be that the relevant documents were destroyed during the war.

Question:

What would have happened regarding the "ownership" of land, and a house build on it, if no owner could be found. Would it become property of the city or state? Would something else happen with it?
I'm asking specifically about the situation in Germany shortly after World War 2.

Comment: This looks like a story based, real world question.

Comment: Yes, it is. I thought of “world building” as coming up with background information for the world the story is set in.

Should I ask this in a different place?

Comment: There is a law.SE where one can ask question about laws in specific countries. Here we help with creating the rules of fictional worlds.

Comment: When you say "after World War 2" do you mean 10ish years after the war, or do you mean the story is set in the present day?

Comment: Depends on the local government(s).  In the US, it would most likely be claimed by the government for unpaid property taxes, and sold.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting the story in Germany after WWII gives you the opportunity to *really* complicate property claims. To prevent the government from seizing the house for unpaid property taxes,

- have it **adjacent or on** (legal interpretations differ and could keep lawyers busy) a former military base
- that was expanded in the 1933-1945 era (restitution claims are mired in murky paperwork)
- and which is now held by the Allied occupation forces,
- except that they are using the main base area and not aware that the haunted house is (or is not?) part of their base.

Basically, the municipal government has filed the house as part of the forest which is now a military training area, while the military believes it is just outside and that they are not responsible.

Depending on how much you want to go into such things, the former owner might have been a Jew murdered by the Nazis, a German who is formally MIA on the Eastern Front but almost certainly dead, a Nazi who is now living under an assumed name in Argentina, ...

Comment: Do military bases send a record of what they build to the local planning office? If not then it sounds like you could still have the **office had no information about the houses existence**. Yes they know who owns the property but not when the house was built or why.

Comment: Though it might be important what "after World War 2" means in the question.

Comment: @Daron, I would have thought that the house should have been a normal civilian home at some point, and older than 1933, to make it properly haunted. So there would be the beginning of a paper trail in the old land registry office. Making that go away completely will be difficult. Hence my suggestion of muddled claims and wartime expediency.

Comment: Thanks for some cool ideas. I wanted to handwave the problem of a completely disappearing paper trail by saying "the archive burned down during the war". The question was intended just to make sure that the first recorded use of the house/land made sense. For that, I really like your idea of ​​a military base.

Answer (score 9):

### It will be claimed by the government for unpaid property taxes

Property taxes in Germany are assessed annually (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxation_in_Germany). Depending on the charity of whoever administers the region, it may be one or a few years - but the property will be eventually seized for unpaid taxes.

### After that, auction or abandoned

The government has discretion. Usually an administrator will try one or several times to get back the missing tax revenue by placing the property up for auction. If the property can't be sold, it may stay abandoned.